# Annoying Intellisense behavior: automatic filling in when typing text after a quotation mark

Tags: intellisense, quotation-marks

This is extremely annoying!  When typing code, after entering a quotation mark, for example:
MyVar = InputBox("
Intellisense continues to make suggestions and fill in variables even though I'm trying to enter something in quotes.  if I try to continue with:
MyVar = InputBox("What is my name?")
Intellisense does this after I enter the space after "is":
MyVar = InputBox("What ISafePathHelper
It drives me nuts!  The only way I can stop it is to go ahead and enter the 2nd quotation mark, then arrow key back one and then enter my text.
Is this a bug?  Is there an option to turn that off?  Please help!

I went through the options and didn't see anything that would help.  I thought at one point it might be the CodeRush extension I had installed but I disabled that and it didn't help.  Previous versions of VS didn't do this to the best of my knowledge.  I have not been able to find any posts anywhere on this problem so maybe it's unique to me?  Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong?